# Get x and y from secp256r1 curve

Tags: android, cryptography, elliptic-curve, android-security

I'm using https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis library for the public key generation which is providing secp256r1 curve. The problem is that PublicKey has only getBytes method but I need to get x and y coordinates. Is it possible to count them having only bytes array of the public key?
I need these coordinates to implement Fido2 and according to documentation:
`Convert the COSE_KEY formatted credentialPublicKey to Raw ANSI X9.62 public key format.`

Comment: It seems that this library is creating key pairs just for its own purpose. The library is not created as a Java provider, otherwise you could e.g. cast to ECPublicKey. Why are you using this library? Is the new Bouncy Castle lib too slow? If I look at the source, the only thing you *can* do is to parse the returned byte array, or indeed change the library.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes how can I parse the returned byte array, is it described anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure of the format of the byte array that you get, I don't know that lib. And I don't know what is meant with "raw" ANSI X9.62 public key format either. Having an example preferably using hexadecimals of both would be helpful.